# weird php OR statement logic

Tags: php

Just noticed weird logic in PHP. Version I'm using is `PHP 5.6.18`.

Code sample:

```
$bet_exists = FALSE;
$unanswered_exists = TRUE;
$answer = $bet_exists OR $unanswered_exists;
if ($bet_exists OR $unanswered_exists)
    $result = TRUE;
} else {
    $result = FALSE;
}
var_dump($answer);
var_dump($result);
```

And the printout is as follows:

```
boolean false
boolean true
```

Are you aware of this behaviour and what is the reason PHP decides to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` and `and` have lower precedences than the assignment `=`.

So the assignment in `$answer = $bet_exists OR $unanswered_exists;` is processed *before* the `or`, hence the value of `$unanswered_exists` does not have any impact (in the third line of your code). It is executed like `($answer = $bet_exists) OR $unanswered_exists;`.

Use `||` and `&&` instead. Like `$answer = $bet_exists && $unanswered_exists;`, which yields the expected result.

And have a look at [operator precedences in PHP](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: but = is a sign of assignment, when == is comparison operator. so PHP decides to first check if equals then OR ?

Comment: @JuscPranskaitis http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php see example, ```// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is test for equality.

Comment: Actually you are wrong on something here. The assignement happens before because the assignement has higher precedence than and/or. It's indicated in the table as well. That's why the assignement won't get the boolean value of the comparison.

Comment: @syck Wondering why you didn't mention use```$answer =  ($bet_exists or $unanswered_exists);``` as solution too!

Comment: @synk your explanation is correct, but you mistaken the precedence in first row of the answer.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @M. I. Thanks, corrected typo. @xdevnull I rather try to avoid `or` and `and` because not many people know about these differences, and I do not want another team member to remove the parens because they think they are not necessary.

Comment: I agree with @xdevnull here. Based on this question, answering with that is far more logical than using the && operator.

Comment: Suggesting parens here would enforce using `and` and `or` for uses which they are not implemented for. They are mainly borrowed from Perl to allow for constructs like `$a = new b() or die('c!');`. The principal operators for logical expressions are still `&&` and `||` whereas `and` and `or` are language constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Use brackets before the assignment  like `$answer = ($bet_exists OR $unanswered_exists);` will also work for the above example.

With out the brackets, the code will act like an assignment ie

```
$answer = $best_exists;
```